# Trying to turn Show/Hide Items filters on and off in Spotfire through script

Tags: python, scripting, spotfire

I have four filters in a Spotfire report that I would like to be able to enable and disable based on selections from a drop-down menu. That menu uses a script to populate existing tables, and I'm struggling with how to set the filters on and off using the script.

Here are my filters (sorry, I don't have enough reputation to embed images):

[image: Filters]

And here's the code I'm attempting to use to select/deselect each one:

```
   found = tableTop.TryGetFilterRules()
   myFilterRuleCollection = found[1]

   if myFilterRuleCollection.Count > 0:
      for myFilterRule in myFilterRuleCollection:
         if myFilterRule.DisplayName == "Hours1":
            myFilterRule.Enabled == True
         else:
            myFilterRule.Enabled == False
```

I feel like I'm *this close* to getting this to work, but nothing happens when I change the menu. I've confirmed that this section of code is embedded within the if statement related to the proper drop-down menu, and I'm not getting any errors on the code, so I feel like I'm missing something obvious. If anyone could help, I would appreciate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you have a typo in your code:

```
     if myFilterRule.DisplayName == "Hours1":
        myFilterRule.Enabled == True
     else:
        myFilterRule.Enabled == False
```

you are using a comparison operator `==` instead of an assignment operator `=` :)